# Use result set to generate dates between entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm very much a basic SQL user. I know the basics and some intermediate skills, but I am having trouble with writing this query.

I have a table called History, and that contains unique entries for a certain piece of data. Here is a stripped down version of what this table looks like:

```
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
| Time                    | ID | ChangeNum | Value |
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
| 2014-07-03 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 0         |  A
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
| 2014-10-02 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 1         |  B
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
| 2014-11-27 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 2         |  C
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
| 2015-01-15 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 3         |  D
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
| 2015-02-14 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 4         |  E
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
| 2015-09-02 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 5         |  F
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
| 2015-09-04 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 6         |  G
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
| 2016-09-13 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 7         |  H
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
| 2016-09-14 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 8         |  I 
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
| 2017-02-12 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 9         |  J
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
| 2017-02-18 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 10        |  K
+-------------------------+----+-----------+-------+
```

What I need to do is make a view that generates data between these date ranges while keeping the rest of the values the same. For example, here's a subset of what the table should look like

```
    +-------------------------+----+-----------+
    | Time                    | ID | ChangeNum |
    +-------------------------+----+-----------+
    | 2014-07-03 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 0         |
    +-------------------------+----+-----------+
    | 2014-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 0         |
    +-------------------------+----+-----------+
    | 2014-07-05 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 0         |
    +-------------------------+----+-----------+
    | 2014-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 0         |
    +-------------------------+----+-----------+
    |        truncated for readability ...     |
    +-------------------------+----+-----------+
    | 2014-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 0         |
    +-------------------------+----+-----------+
    | 2014-10-02 00:00:00.000 | 3  | 1         |
    +-------------------------+----+-----------+
```

I have seen posts like this where I can generate a date range using a CTE, and that's simple enough. However, this involves **looping through a result set** in the History table, getting the lower and upper bounds for the date ranges (the first row's Time field, and then the next row's Time field), and then generating the data **between these rows.** This might be easier than I'm making it seem, but I'm a little lost. My initial thought was to use cursors, but I don't exactly know how to do this in the context of lagging / leading in a table. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You definitely do not need a cursor for this. You need a tally table.

Comment: The two answers both utilize tally tables, which I have never heard of. Can this be achieved using regular SQL syntax (e.g. not using variables or table creation)? Also, isn't this a good candidate for a 'Gaps and Islands' solution, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @psrpsrpsr My answer doesn't use a tally table, but I don't think you can do this without a variable or a tally table.  You'd likely need one or the other to produce the missing date records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fun way of doing this, though I'm making some assumptions based on your example data:

```
--This is your current table
CREATE TABLE #TEST
(timefield datetime,
id int,
ChangeNum int)

INSERT INTO #TEST (TIMEFIELD, ID, CHANGENUM)
VALUES
('2014-07-03 00:00:00.000', 3, 0),
('2014-10-02 00:00:00.000', 3, 1),
('2014-11-27 00:00:00.000', 3, 2),
('2015-01-15 00:00:00.000', 3, 3),
('2015-02-14 00:00:00.000', 3, 4)

--This is your destination table
CREATE TABLE #TEST2
(timefield datetime,
 id int,
 ChangeNum int)

--This is where we INSERT from your source to destination table
DECLARE @TIMEFIELD datetime = '2014-07-03 00:00:00.000' --Your start date
DECLARE @ChangeNum int = 0 --Starting ChangeNum

WHILE @TIMEFIELD <= '2015-02-14 00:00:00.000' --Your end date
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #TEST2
 SELECT @TIMEFIELD, 3, @ChangeNum;

 SET @TIMEFIELD = DATEADD(DD, 1, @TIMEFIELD);

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TEST WHERE TIMEFIELD = @TIMEFIELD)
  BEGIN
   SET @ChangeNum = (SELECT ChangeNum FROM #TEST WHERE TIMEFIELD = @TIMEFIELD)
   --This part can be modified to account for more columns
  END
END

SELECT * FROM #TEST2 --The new table
```

**Edit** Changed things so it will work for all IDs, even with different dates and ChangeNums:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST
(timefield datetime,
id int,
ChangeNum int)

INSERT INTO #TEST (TIMEFIELD, ID, CHANGENUM)
VALUES
('2014-07-03 00:00:00.000', 3, 0),
('2014-10-02 00:00:00.000', 3, 1),
('2014-11-27 00:00:00.000', 3, 2),
('2015-01-15 00:00:00.000', 3, 3),
('2015-02-14 00:00:00.000', 3, 4),
('2014-11-27 00:00:00.000', 2, 2),
('2015-01-15 00:00:00.000', 2, 3),
('2015-02-14 00:00:00.000', 2, 4),
('2014-10-02 00:00:00.000', 1, 1),
('2014-11-27 00:00:00.000', 1, 2),
('2015-01-15 00:00:00.000', 1, 3),
('2015-02-14 00:00:00.000', 1, 4)

CREATE TABLE #TEST2
(timefield datetime,
id int,
ChangeNum int)

DECLARE @ID int = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #TEST)
DECLARE @ChangeNum int = (SELECT MIN(ChangeNum) FROM #TEST WHERE @ID = ID)
DECLARE @TIMEFIELD datetime = (SELECT MIN(TIMEFIELD) FROM #TEST WHERE @ID = ID)

WHILE @ID <= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #TEST)
BEGIN

WHILE @TIMEFIELD <= (SELECT MAX(TIMEFIELD) FROM #TEST WHERE ID = @ID)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #TEST2
   SELECT @TIMEFIELD, @ID, @ChangeNum
   SET @TIMEFIELD = DATEADD(DD, 1, @TIMEFIELD)

   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TEST WHERE TIMEFIELD = @TIMEFIELD AND ID = @ID)
   BEGIN
    SET @ChangeNum = (SELECT ChangeNum FROM #TEST WHERE TIMEFIELD = @TIMEFIELD AND ID = @ID);
   END

  END

  IF EXISTS (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #TEST WHERE ID > @ID)
   BEGIN
    SET @ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #TEST WHERE ID > @ID)
    SET @ChangeNum = (SELECT MIN(ChangeNum) FROM #TEST WHERE @ID = ID)
    SET @TIMEFIELD = (SELECT MIN(TIMEFIELD) FROM #TEST WHERE @ID = ID)
   END
END

SELECT * FROM #TEST2
```

Comment: Awesome - this was fairly straight forward. I modified it to the particulars of my environment - certain tables and variables needed, my particular SQL Engine syntax, etc - but this worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @dxh9845 Glad to hear it, this was a fun one to do!  Not sure if you need this now, but I didn't like that it was hardcoded for `ID=3` and was pretty much not scale-able whatsoever, so I edited in a new answer that will work for each ID/ChangeNum/Date combination.

Comment: Honestly pretty funny- I was enabling this to work in a loop but you beat me to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was fun.  As Sean said, you need a tally table or in my words a Dates table.  [This is where I got the Dates table from.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)  This doesn't take into account what will happen if two changes where made on the same day.  I also shortened the time frame to make testing easier.  This does account for multiple IDs being returned.

```
CREATE TABLE #test (ID INT, ChangeNum INT, [Value] varchar(1), [Time] datetime);

    DECLARE @StartDate datetime
        , @CutoffDate datetime;

INSERT INTO #test ([time], ID, ChangeNum, [Value])
VALUES 
('2011-07-03 00:00:00.000',  3, 0, 'A'),
('2011-07-10 00:00:00.000',  3, 1, 'B'),
('2011-07-15 00:00:00.000',  3, 2, 'C'),    
('2011-07-01 00:00:00.000',  2, 0, 'Q'),
('2011-07-06 00:00:00.000',  2, 1, 'R'),
('2011-08-03 00:00:00.000',  2, 2, 'S');    

    SELECT @StartDate = MIN([Time])
        ,@CutoffDate = MAX([time])
    FROM #test;

WITH Dates
AS (SELECT d
    FROM (
        SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1, @StartDate)
        FROM (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
            FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
            CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
            ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
            ) AS x
        ) AS y
    )
     ,ChangeRanges
    AS (
        SELECT ID
            , [Time] BEGIN_DATE
            , CASE WHEN LEAD ([Time], 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, [time]) = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN [Time] 
                    ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -1, LEAD ([Time], 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, [time])) END END_DATE 
            , ChangeNum
        FROM #test
)       
    SELECT d.d [DATE]
            ,cr.ID
            ,cr.ChangeNum
    FROM ChangeRanges cr
    JOIN Dates d ON d.d >= cr.BEGIN_DATE AND d.d <= cr.END_DATE
    WHERE ID = 3
    GROUP BY cr.ID, d.d, cr.ChangeNum
    ORDER BY cr.ID, d.d

DROP TABLE #test
```

Comment: Just clarifying my answer doesn't use a tally table, it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: I agree @AaronDietz. A tally table isn't absolutely necessary. There are just too many instances where the looping solution because too burdensome or cannot work (reporting for instance).  If you just need the list in SSMS a loop works just fine.

Comment: I also didn't notice that you were in 2008.  Mine doesn't work in that version.

Comment: I'd say tag your answer **SQL-Server 2012+** option at the top, it's still a neat and useful answer if anyone else happens to drop by.